# How does the splitting type of a prime $p$ in a field $K$ (not Galois) determine its splitting type in its Galois closure $\tilde{K}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In general, if a rational prime $p$ factos in the ring of integers of a number field $K$ (not Galois), is the factorisation of $p$ in the ring of integers of its Galois closure $\tilde{K}$ completely determined by how it factors in $\mathcal{O}_K$?

My advisor seems to think this is the case but I am unsure why this is obvious. I would appreciate a few hints or a reference where I can read more about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know some $p$-adic number theory ?  With $L$ the Galois closure, if $p\nmid [L:\Bbb{Q}]$, with $Q_j$ and $P_i$ the primes of $O_L$ and $O_K$ above $p$ then $L_{w_j} = \Bbb{Q}_p(p^{-1/e(Q_j/p)},\zeta_{f(Q_j/p)-1}) = \prod_i L_{w_i}=\prod K_{v_i}$ which is both containing and contained in $ \prod_i \Bbb{Q}_p(p^{-1/e(P_i/p)},\zeta_{f(P_i/p)-1}) $ thus $e(Q_j/p)=lcm(\{e(P_i/p)\}_i),f(Q_j/p)=lcm(\{f(P_i/p)\}_i)$

Comment: Hi, I am rather unfamiliar with the things you have mentioned. Would you mind telling me where I can learn more about these? Thanks!

Comment: You can search for $p$-adic completion and tamely ramified extension here on MSE